# insert value to php array with index

Tags: arrays, array-push

Hello I have this array :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "35"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "33"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "50"
}
```

That I obtain using this :

```
$groupstring = $_POST['groupstring'];
$groupstring =  stripslashes($groupstring);
$blah = unserialize($groupstring);

var_dump($blah);
```

this is what's inside the var groupstring : `a:3:{i:0;s:2:"35";i:1;s:2:"33";i:2;s:2:"50";}`

I want to insert a new value for example 38 at the end. I tried `array_push($array, '38')`
but it failed I understand there is an index. what would be the best way to do it? thanks much!!

Comment: Could you provide the code that fails?

Comment: @Guillaume I updated the code Guillaume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$groupstring = $_POST['groupstring'];
$groupstring =  stripslashes($groupstring);
$blah = unserialize($groupstring);

$blah[] = 38;
var_dump($blah);
```

Comment: "array_push($blah, 38);" works too... so I still don't understand what was the problem at first...

Comment: Guillaume I had an undefined variable instead of $fid I was using $id. It was my fault sorry.